# Validando somente cpfs com numeros diferentes

Tags: c++, validação

Boa noite galera precisava fazer na função abaixo uma forma de invalidar cpfs digitados com numeros iguais por ex:

123456789
000000000
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
999999999

seriam todos invalidos pois nao existem: entao tenho a seguinte função abaixo para validar cpf:

inline bool isCpf()
 {
  int digito1;
  int digito2;
  int temp = 0;
  const int *cpf;
    /*Obtendo o primeiro digito verificador:

```
Os 9 primeiros algarismos são multiplicados pela sequência 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
(o primeiro por 10, o segundo por 9, e assim por diante);
Em seguida, calcula-se o resto “r1″ da divisão da soma dos resultados das multiplicações por 11,
e se o resto for zero ou 1, digito é zero, caso contrário digito = (11-r1) */
for(char i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 temp += (cpf[i] * (10 - i));
  temp %= 11;

if(temp < 2)
 digito1 = 0;
  else
   digito1 = 11 - temp;

/*Obtendo o segundo digito verificador:
O dígito2 é calculado pela mesma regra, porém inclui-se o primeiro digito verificador ao final
da sequencia. Os 10 primeiros algarismos são multiplicados pela sequencia 11, 10, 9, ... etc...
(o primeiro por 11, o segundo por 10, e assim por diante);
procedendo da mesma maneira do primeiro digito*/
temp = 0;
 for(char i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  temp += (cpf[i] * (11 - i));
   temp %= 11;

if(temp < 2)
 digito2 = 0;
  else
   digito2 = 11 - temp;

/* Se os digitos verificadores obtidos forem iguais aos informados pelo usuário,
   então o CPF é válido */
if(digito1 == cpf[9] && digito2 == cpf[10])
 return true;
  else
   return false;
```

}

e para nao ficar com aquele monte de if e else fiz isso

inline bool isCpf()
 {
  int digito1;
  int digito2;
  int temp = 0;
  const int *cpf;
    /*Obtendo o primeiro digito verificador:

```
Os 9 primeiros algarismos são multiplicados pela sequência 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
(o primeiro por 10, o segundo por 9, e assim por diante);
Em seguida, calcula-se o resto “r1″ da divisão da soma dos resultados das multiplicações por 11,
e se o resto for zero ou 1, digito é zero, caso contrário digito = (11-r1) */
for(char i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 temp += (cpf[i] * (10 - i));
  temp %= 11;

if(temp < 2)
 digito1 = 0;
  else
   digito1 = 11 - temp;

/*Obtendo o segundo digito verificador:
O dígito2 é calculado pela mesma regra, porém inclui-se o primeiro digito verificador ao final
da sequencia. Os 10 primeiros algarismos são multiplicados pela sequencia 11, 10, 9, ... etc...
(o primeiro por 11, o segundo por 10, e assim por diante);
procedendo da mesma maneira do primeiro digito*/
temp = 0;
 for(char i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  temp += (cpf[i] * (11 - i));
   temp %= 11;

if(temp < 2)
 digito2 = 0;
  else
   digito2 = 11 - temp;

if (digito1==cpf[10] && digito2==cpf[11])
  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)cpf[i]==i;
   std::cout << "\n\tCPF Invalido - Digitos Iguais\n\n"; 

/* Se os digitos verificadores obtidos forem iguais aos informados pelo usuário,
   então o CPF é válido */
if(digito1 == cpf[9] && digito2 == cpf[10])
 return true;
  else
   return false;
```

}

entao pesquisei um site que gerasse cpf' validos:
http://geradordecpf.clevert.com.br/

ele gerou os seguintes cpfs validos:

101.884.251-95
766.381.650-11
072.306.886-04
518.220.106-08
320.377.006-79

adicionei esta parte ao codigo para
invalidar cpfs com numeros iguais mas
ele esta fazendo com que até o meu
cpf pessoal seja invalido se eu digitar pois o programa esta fazendo a verificação correta dos digitos para validação:

if (digito1==cpf[10] && digito2==cpf[11])
 for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)cpf[i]==i;
  std::cout << "\n\tCPF Invalido - Digitos Iguais\n\n";

Oprograma recebe o cpf sem pontos ou traços,
entao o cpf abaixo é validado sem usar esta parte do codigo:
76638165011

e se eu trocar por 382 ele é invalido o programa nao estavalidanfo formato de entrada e sim a verificação correta dos numeros.
76638265011

a minha dúvida gira em torno da invalidação de cpfs com digitos iguais aos mencionados, mas que nao torne invalido se eu entrar com meu proprio cpf pessoal ou com um cpf valido nao somente na quantidade de digitos mas sim com verificador valido.

Este é o programa conpleto: 
https://pastebin.com/djeibpRZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função abaixo é capaz de verificar se uma string (no caso um CPF) é composto por uma sequencia de caracteres repetidos, retorna `0` caso uma sequencia seja detectada:

```
int verificar_sequencia( const char * cpf )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = strlen(cpf);

    for( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        if( cpf[i] != cpf[i-1] )
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo: https://github.com/LacobusVentura/CPF-Gen/blob/master/cpfgen.c

Comment: eu adaptei sua função para dentro da função bool da seguinte forma:     int n = sizeof(cpf);
    
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
     if(cpf[i] != cpf[i-1])
      return true;
        return false;  mas ainda continua validando os seguintes digitos: 123456789

Comment: Não se preocupe em validar sequências numéricas, segundo a Receita Federal, em um documento entitulado [Ato Declaratório Executivo nº 1, Anexo I de 23 de Maio de 2002](http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/publico/Legislacao/atos/AtosConjuntos/AnexoIADEConjuntoCoratCotec0012002.doc), CPFs formados por sequências também são válidos!